# How to create a valid request to autosuggest in HERE API?

Tags: api, web-services, oauth-2.0, autocomplete, geolocation

I read documentation and tried solving problem on my own but I am stuck. I am trying to make example call from docs:

```
https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/
    autosuggest
    ?at=52.93175,12.77165
    &limit=5
    &lang=en
    &q=res
    &apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

This is my code that makes a get request (in Angular)

```
getPlaces() {
    const bearer = 'my bearer'
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${bearer}`
    })
    return this.http.get('https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest 
      at=52.93175,12.77165&limit=5&lang=en&q=res&apiKey={MY_KEY}', {headers: headers})
}
```

What i get is respone:

```
{
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "error_description": "These credentials do not authorize access"
}
status: 403
statusText: "Forbidden"
```

To generate bearer I use olp as stated here:
[get token with the cli](https://developer.here.com/documentation/identity-access-management/dev_guide/topics/plat-token.html#get-a-token-with-the-cli)

In docs in examples of usage there is no bearer, but without it I get the same result. I tried searching for similar problems but I found nothing that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well i found solutution but i did not see any mention about this in docs: you have to add service in services tab in project manager :)
Only API_KEY is needed - OAuth2 and bearer is not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).